# Node JS use all files in folder

Tags: node.js, express, npm, ejs

server.js

```
// Imports
const express = require('express')
const expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts')
const app = express()
const port = 5000
app.use(express.static('utils'))
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + 'utils/css'))
app.use(expressLayouts)
app.set('layout', './layouts/full-width')
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.get('', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Home Page'})})
app.get('/about', (req, res) => {
    res.render('about', { title: 'About Page'})})
app.listen(port, () => console.info(`App listening on port http://127.0.0.1:${port}`))
```

How can i make node use all the .ejs files in 1 folder, without having to add them in every time? i cant seem to figure out how.

Folder layout:

```
--utils
---css
---js
---img
--------
--views
---layouts (folder)
---partials (folder, head and foot)
---index.ejs
---about.ejs
--------
--server.js
```

What my goal is, you add *something*.ejs and node automatically adds an app.get request (also accounting for if one is in a folder, like /views/link/index.ejs will go to /link/index.ejs etc)

Comment: building your app out you will actually find you do want to set the specific view, but don't forget you can do `app.get('/:view'` then do `res.render(req.params.view,...` but that would require you to check it exists else your have an ugly error message, or you could define and object/array of valid views.. extra steps

Comment: tbh, your code doesn't need a template engine as-is, move `title` into the html and simply use static

Comment: well the template egine does the sidebar, header, footer etc.... how could i load the other parts without a template? and as for the views, i want to be able to just drag and drop a file, like i can do with PHP or Apache2 (drop the file, and wala)

Comment: code it https://repl.it/@lcherone/CreepyFunctionalPort#index.js but you may regret it as the app builds out, also when using a router in php, one cant simply copy the file you still have to assign the route, is same thing